# Is there a way to create a foreign key violation using the DELETE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am studying SQL questions to improve my knowledge, and found [this](https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/oracle/view/15064-exam-1z0-071-topic-1-question-268-discussion/) example:

```
Which statement is true about TRUNCATE and DELETE?

A. You can never TRUNCATE a table if foreign key constraints will be violated.
B. For large tables TRUNCATE is faster than DELETE.
C. For tables with multiple indexes and triggers DELETE is faster than TRUNCATE.
D. You can never DELETE rows from a table if foreign key constraints will be violated.
```

And supposedly only B is correct. I am not able to come up with a way to use delete in a way will violate foreign key constraints. Why isn’t D correct as well?

Here is an example:

```
create table question (id integer primary key );
create table answer (fk integer REFERENCES question (id));

insert into question values (1);
insert into answer values(1);

commit;

delete from question; << will not work due to the foreign key reference
delete from answer; << will work: now the question has no answers, but this does not violate the foreign key.
```

Comment: Delete a row with a primary key that is referenced from another table.

Comment: The question is imprecise as well: `TRUNCATE` and `DELETE` are equivalent only if the `DELETE` has no `WHERE`. If the `DELETE` has a `WHERE`, of course, it may well be faster than a `TRUNCATE`!

Comment: @JohnWu The foreign key only points into one direction, I don't see where the constraint violations appears. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, forget what I wrote (I will delete those answers after some time, since they are wrong and misleading). You are asking, why is D **not** "true". I misread that. In fact D (and also A) are true. The examiners probably want you to think about the `CASCADE` option (you can delete even if there are dependent rows still in existence), but that will not result in a FK violation; instead, it will result in the statement deleting or truncating more than the specifically indicated scope, precisely so that a FK constraint will **not** be violated. You are right and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book question is tricky and might be written not completely correctly, but here is the deal: option B is correct, option C is obviously not correct.

The question in A and D is basically about **ON DELETE Clause** in Oracle, which allows you to delete referenced key values in the parent table that have dependent rows in the child table - [Oracle Docs - ON DELETE Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#:%7E:text=or%20more%20columns.-,ON%20DELETE%20Clause%C2%A0,-The%20ON%20DELETE)

> Specify ON DELETE CASCADE if you want Oracle to remove dependent foreign key values.
>
> Specify ON DELETE SET NULL if you want Oracle to convert dependent foreign key values to NULL.

So options A and D basically mean that in some cases we actually CAN DELETE rows or TRUNCATE table even if it's against foreign key constraints rules.
[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/truncate-table-cascade-12cr1) are a lot of examples of using this clause.

*Optional information:* there is one more way to TRUNCATE table even if ON DELETE clause was not set: [Oracle Docs - TRUNCATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10007.htm#:%7E:text=Restrictions%20on%20Truncating%20Tables%C2%A0)

> You cannot truncate the parent table of an enabled foreign key constraint. You must disable the constraint before truncating the table. **An exception is that you can truncate the table if the integrity constraint is self-referential.**

Example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST_EMP (
CUST_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT MAN_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_ID)
REFERENCES TEST_EMP (CUST_ID)
);

SQL>
Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEST_EMP VALUES (1,'John',NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST_EMP VALUES (2,'Maria',1);
INSERT INTO TEST_EMP VALUES (3,'Julia',1);
INSERT INTO TEST_EMP VALUES (4,'Steve',2);
commit;

SQL>
4 rows inserted.

SQL>
Commit complete.
   
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE TEST_EMP;

Table truncated.

SQL> DROP TABLE TEST_EMP;

Table dropped.
```

Comment: Great answer. This is a typical "weasel word" exam question. Note the word _never_ in the question... meaning that if there is any tiny edge case allowing you to do it (i.e. the 1ON DELETE` clause mentioned above), then the "never" in the question is not true.

Comment: Thanks! Considering the cascade option, there will be no foreign key violation after all, right? So would you say answer D is wrong or correct?

Comment: @Beginner, in a real life I would say, that this violates foreign key, however, within the exam world its not.  Taking into account that there can be only 1 correct answer, I'm saying it should be B.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can have deferred constraints, which are not enforced until the end of the transaction. A TRUNCATE includes a commit so it doesn't make a difference there. However it would allow for a DELETE statement to violate a deferred constraint.

"The DEFERRABLE and NOT DEFERRABLE parameters indicate whether or not, in subsequent transactions, constraint checking can be deferred until the end of the transaction using the SET CONSTRAINT(S) statement. If you omit this clause, then the default is NOT DEFERRABLE."

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE